# How to set Network Preference parameters for headless browser PhantomJS with Python and Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

How to implement below profile set preference for Phantomjs headless browser.

```
def browser():
    print("Setting up webdriver connection...")
    global driver
    if driver is None:
        profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type",1)
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http","web-proxy.xxxx.xx.com")
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.https","web-proxy.xxxx.xx.com")
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl","web-proxy.xxxx.xx.com")
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port",8080)
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.https_port",8080)
        profile.set_preference("network.proxy.ssl_port",8080)
        profile.update_preferences()
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
        driver.maximize_window()
        yield driver
        driver.quit()
```

I am using python 2.7, selenium 3.0 and phantomjs 1.9.7.

Answer (score 0):

To set the **Network Preferences** for **PhantomJS Headless Browser** you can use the argument **`service_args`** as follows :

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path="/path/to/phantomjs", service_args=['--proxy-type=[http|socks5|none]', '--proxy=address:port'])
```

An Example on Windows OS:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe', service_args=['--proxy-type=http', '--proxy=web-proxy.xxxx.xx.com:8080'])
```

**Note** : Consider upgrading to latest ***Selenium/Python Client v3.12.0*** and latest ***PhantomJS Release v2.1.1***